# Friend functions in structures or classes

Tags: c++

I wonder why when I'm using the key word friend in C++ to overload the << operator, I get no error but when I don't use the friend key word, I get an error!

```
struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    bool operator<(const Student& s) const
    {
        return this->age < s.age;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& s);
};
```

and I define my function in the main.cpp as shown :

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& s)
{
    os << s.name;
}
```

the error is when I don't use the friend key word is:
" too many parameters to this operator "
can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2):

When you don't write `friend`, you are declaring a *member* function. This means that the left-hand side parameter of a call like `a << b` is the instance of the class you are working with. Therefore, you only need to specify the right-hand side parameter, which will be the only one.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear but can you explain me a little bit? :)

Comment: " This means that the left-hand side parameter of a call like a << b is the instance of the class you are working with" this please

Comment: @Idriss When you write `a.f(b)`, you are calling member function `f` on the instance `a` with parameter `b`, right? In a similar way, when you write `a << b`, you are calling `operator<<`, and you have two "parameters": the LHS (`a`) and the RHS (`b`). If the operator is a member function, then `a` is implicit like in the `a.f(b)` example. So `b` is the only parameter you have to write. In fact, in that case, `a << b` can be rewritten as `a.operator<<(b)`.

Comment: oh that's really a nice explanation, thank you so much